# Speedup re-projecting rasters in FME Desktop!

Tags: coordinate-system, raster-conversion, fme-form

I am trying to re-project some aerial photos (at the resolution 20cm) using Esri re-projector in FME Desktop 2017, and i it takes too much time reprojecting (10-15x slower) comparing to ArcGIS.

Is there any configuration i can do to speed it up?

Mosaicking rasters doesn't take that much, it works normal, but re-projecting takes too much time.

Comment: What version of Desktop? How much RAM is available? 64bit is much faster.

Comment: HP Z600, 16 ram, Intel Xeon 2.4, Windows 7 ultimate 64bit. But i use 32bit version because Esri reprojector doesnt work in 64 bit

Comment: If you run the 64bit version of ArcGIS (ie Pro) you can use the ESRIReprojecter in the 64 bit FME version (they both have to be the same). https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/esrireprojector.htm

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything else going on in the workspace? For example are you also mosaicking? Generally the logs can be hard to decipher because so much happens at once making it hard to tell where the bottleneck is. And with raster generally, any transformation is stored up as a matrix of actions and only carried out when the data is being written, which makes it even harder to analyze performance.

So it's better sometimes to analyze performance empirically.

I would suggest trying to tie this down to a specific process. For example, first read the data by itself (no transformers or writers) to see how long that takes.

Then try reprojection but using a Null writer; in essence it's like writing to nul on a filesystem (the data is received but discarded). If it is just as slow then it's likely the reprojection is the problem. If it's a lot quicker, then the reprojection is sound but the writing is the bottleneck.

If the reprojection is the problem, more memory is one simple solution. Use 64-bit FME (as suggested above) to facilitate that. If writing is a problem... do you have a fanout set? That can slow things up.

Also, when you have multiple raster transformations going on (like mosaicking AND reprojecting) the RasterCheckpointer transformer can sometimes help. It forces processing to be carried out immediately, rather than waiting till writing. Sometimes it's quicker that way (I won't go into details why, but give it a try by placing one after one raster transformer and before another).

Comment: No i do only projection , but maybe it is the limitation of 32bit version, i do the same transformation in Esri and it is very fast.